# fsockopen on local host connection refused

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

I'm using a WAMP running on windows 8.1 machine. I'm trying to establish a tcp connect to windows application (I don't have a source code, just instructions on which port to connect) on same machine using fsocketopen.

```
$fs = fsockopen('127.0.0.1',1201, $en, $es, $timeout);
```

And error message is: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
I've disabled windows firewall and avg, checked if sockets are enabled and wamp and i'm out of solutions now.
Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Comment: Try running `netstat` on your machine. See if there's anything listening on the port you mentioned. Conn Refused means - nobody is listening there. on that port.

Comment: Start windows app as Administrator? Is the app running within the VM?

Answer (score 0):

First update your web service references used in your application.
If web service references are not get updated, then check all files and folder containing source code files in your web service project solution and rebuild it and then update web references used in your project.
Else if its working fine then you need to check your network services used by your development server and windows firewall settings as suggested in above solutions.

I also encountered same problem and I came to know that I was referencing wrong folder having same name but used in another solution.

Also Make sure your connection is not in proxy mode. In Windows 7 go to "Internet Options" in "Connection" tab click on "LAN Settings" and uncheck everything.